# VBA - use specified order for tie-breaker

Tags: excel, vba

```
Value1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AE1:AE5000"), “firststring”)
Value2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AE1:AE5000"), “secondstring”)
Value3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AE1:AE5000"), “thirdstring”)
Value4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AE1:AE5000"), “fourthstring”)

MaxValue = WorksheetFunction.Max(Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4)

If MaxValue = Value1 Then
'Do something
ElseIf MaxValue = Value2 Then
'Do another thing
ElseIf MaxValue = Value3 Then
'Do yet another thing
ElseIf MaxValue = Value4 Then
'Do another thing
End If
```

I'm trying to run different parts of my script depending on which of the 4 integer variables holds the highest value. However, I'm not sure how to code in a tiebreaker condition e.g. if there are multiple variables with the same highest value, Value1 will be treated as the highest value, followed by Value2, Value3 and Value4, in that order.

Comment: Do you intent do manually writhe that these variables in the code? Aren't them in a range, array or something? Having them in an array it is easy to handle the problem, as you describe it. Do you like the code doing different things according to the variable occurrence? I mean to do something for the firs occurrence and something else for the rest of occurrences...

Comment: @FaneDuru Basically it calls different macros depending on which variable holds the highest value.  These variables are counters if it helps to clear things up a bit

Comment: Not so clear... Where these 'counters' are taken from? I was asking if it is convenient for you to manually place the 'counters' inside the function parenthesis. I cannot believe that this is the single way, very inefficient, anyway...

Comment: I don't understand your problem. In your example, `MaxValue = Value1`, the first *Do Something* will be executed and that's it. The fact that `MaxValue = Value2` is also true doesn't matter as this is part of an `ElseIf`-branch that will not be hit when the `If`-part was already true.

Comment: @FaneDuru The 'counters' are taken from counting the total number of different string occurrences in a column. I'm not sure how to place these counters within a function though

Comment: @FunThomas Yes, the point is to just run one of the four if statements depending on which variable holds the highest value. I'm just not sure how to set a tiebreaker if multiple variables have the same highest value

Comment: Your current tie breaker is the order defined in your `If ... `ElseIf`. If you need a different tiebreaker, you need first to be clear what that would be - noone can answer that for you.

Comment: @FunThomas oh, that actually answered my question, but i cant accept a comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already does what it should do. `WorksheetFunction.Max` gives you the highest value. You then compare that max value with your variables. When Value1 holds the maximum, the *`Do something`* for value1 is executed and the complete If-statement is left (the runtime will not check any of the other cases).

When two variables have the same value, the tie-breaker will be simply the order of your checks in the If- resp ElseIf-statement. Assuming that value2 and value4 have both the maximum, the runtime will see the `ElseIf maxvalue = value2` statement first, execute the *`Do something`* for value2 and that's it. This is the nature of `If ... ElseIf ... Else ... Endif` statements

Answer (score 2):

### Tie Breaker

**Do One Thing Applied**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TieBreaker()
    
    Const CriteriaList As String = "first,second,third,fourth"
    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(CriteriaList, ",")
    
    Dim n As Long: n = UBound(Criteria)
    
    Dim Data() As Long: ReDim Data(0 To n)
    
    For n = 0 To n
        Data(n) = Application.CountIf(Range("AE1:AE5000"), Criteria(n))
    Next n
    
    Dim cMax As Long: cMax = Application.Max(Data)
    Dim cIndex As Long: cIndex = Application.Match(cMax, Data, 0) - 1
    
    Select Case cIndex
    Case 0
        'Do something
        Debug.Print 0, Data(0), Criteria(0)
    Case 1
        'Do another thing
        Debug.Print 1, Data(1), Criteria(1)
    Case 2
        'Do yet another thing
        Debug.Print 2, Data(2), Criteria(2)
    Case 3
        'Do another thing
        Debug.Print 3, Data(3), Criteria(3)
    End Select

End Sub
```

**Do Only One Thing**

```
Sub TieBreaker()
    
    Dim value1 As Long: value1 = 2
    Dim value2 As Long: value2 = 3
    Dim value3 As Long: value3 = 3
    Dim value4 As Long: value4 = 1

    Dim Data(1 To 4) As Long
    Data(1) = value1
    Data(2) = value2
    Data(3) = value3
    Data(4) = value4
    
    Dim cMax As Long: cMax = Application.Max(Data)
    Dim cIndex As Long: cIndex = Application.Match(cMax, Data, 0)
    
    Select Case cIndex
    Case 1
        'Do something
        Debug.Print 1, Data(1)
    Case 2
        'Do another thing
        Debug.Print 2, Data(2)
    Case 3
        'Do yet another thing
        Debug.Print 3, Data(3)
    Case 4
        'Do another thing
        Debug.Print 4, Data(4)
    End Select

End Sub
```

**The Result**

```
 2             3
```

**Do All Things in a Descending Order**

```
Sub TieBreakerAll()
    
    Dim value1 As Long: value1 = 2
    Dim value2 As Long: value2 = 3
    Dim value3 As Long: value3 = 3
    Dim value4 As Long: value4 = 1

    Dim Data(1 To 4, 1 To 2) As Long
    Data(1, 1) = value1: Data(1, 2) = 1
    Data(2, 1) = value2: Data(2, 2) = 2
    Data(3, 1) = value3: Data(3, 2) = 3
    Data(4, 1) = value4: Data(4, 2) = 4
    
    ' Bubble Sort
    Dim tmp(1 To 2) As Long
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    For i = 1 To 3
        For k = i + 1 To 4
            If Data(i, 1) < Data(k, 1) Then
                tmp(1) = Data(i, 1): tmp(2) = Data(i, 2)
                Data(i, 1) = Data(k, 1): Data(i, 2) = Data(k, 2)
                Data(k, 1) = tmp(1): Data(k, 2) = tmp(2)
            End If
        Next k
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To 4
        
        k = Data(i, 2) ' the order
        
        Select Case k
        Case 1
            'Do something
            Debug.Print 1, Data(i, 1)
        Case 2
            'Do another thing
            Debug.Print 2, Data(i, 1)
        Case 3
            'Do yet another thing
            Debug.Print 3, Data(i, 1)
        Case 4
            'Do another thing
            Debug.Print 4, Data(i, 1)
        End Select
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

**The Result**

```
 2             3 
 3             3 
 1             2 
 4             1
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably would need `Dictionary` object to create associations in first place.

```
Dim objDic As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim maxVal
Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With objDic
    .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    .Add "firststring", Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AE1:AE5000"), "firststring")
    .Add "secondstring", Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AE1:AE5000"), "secondstring")
    .Add "thirdstring", Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AE1:AE5000"), "thirdstring")
    .Add "fourthstring", Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AE1:AE5000"), "fourthstring")
End With

maxVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(objDic.Items)
For i = 0 To objDic.Count - 1
    If objDic.Items()(i) = maxVal Then
        Debug.Print objDic.Keys()(i)
    End If
Next i
```